# AutoCompleteTextField retrieving null when page is refreshed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set the AutoCompleteTextField but when I navigate from one page to the other also by sending & receiving the same entered value the value is not getting displayed in the AutoCompleteTextField. And also when I tap in the suggestions I'm getting an error

> The getter 'controller' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: controller

Code:

```
class CustomRegistration extends StatefulWidget {
final String pincodeC;
CustomRegistration([this.pincodeC])
  @override
  _CustomRegistrationState createState() => _CustomRegistrationState();
}

class _CustomRegistrationState extends State<CustomRegistration> {
FocusNode pincodeFocus = new FocusNode();
TextEditingController pincode = new TextEditingController();
List<String> suggestionList = ['170010','110011','170001'];
SimpleAutoCompleteTextField textField;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
     Column body = new Column(children: [
      new ListTile(
        title: textField,)
    ]);
    body.children.addAll(added.map((item) {
      return new ListTile(title: new Text(item));
    }));

    print(textField); 
 
    return Scaffold(
     body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                 AutoCompleteTextField(
                              focusNode: pincodeFocus,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
                                hintText: "Pincode",
                              ),
                              controller: pincode,
                              itemSubmitted: (item) {
                                setState(() {
                                  textField.controller.text = item.toString();
                                  print('item submitted' + item.toString());
                                });
                              },
                              key: key,
                              suggestions: suggestionList,
                              itemBuilder: (context, item){
                                return Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        item,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              itemSorter: (a, b) {
                                return a.compareTo(b);
                              },
                              itemFilter: (item, query) {
                                return item
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .toString()
                                    .startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
                              },
                            ),
                          ]))));}}
```

When I'm printing the textfield I get **null** and where to initialize the **widget.pincodeC** ?

Comment: Why do you want to send the controller from 1 page to another. That may not be right. When you go to next page the previous page text fled itself may have been destroyed and hence the controller will become invalid. Instead just send the value of the testfield `controller.text`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your kind assistance, i did get the result by adding `pincode.text = widget.pincodeC;`  inside build